# Powershell's Update Entity command for azure table storage

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-table-storage

I need some example or tutorials on use of azure table storage in powershell. I know how to create tables, insert entities, and display entities. But, can anyone give me any direction towards update case. How to update an existing entity in a table in powershell? How to check/access a particular column of an entity in a table in powershell?

Script to add an entity:

```
function InsertRow($table, [String]$partitionKey, [String]$rowKey, [int]$intValue)
{
  $entity = New-Object "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity" $partitionKey, $rowKey
  $entity.Properties.Add("IntValue", $intValue)
  $result = $table.CloudTable.Execute([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation]::Insert($entity))
}

$StorageAccountName = "storageName"
$StorageAccountKey = "StorageKey"

$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey

$tablename = "test"

$table = Get-AzureStorageTable $tablename -Context $context -ErrorAction Ignore
if ($table -eq $null)
{
    New-AzureStorageTable $tablename -Context $context
}

for ($p = 1; $p -le 1; $p++)
{
  for ($r = 1; $r -le 1; $r++)
  {
    InsertRow $table "P$p" "R$r" $r
  }
}
```

Script to display all entities in a table:

```
$query = New-Object Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery

#Define columns to select.
$list = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
$list.Add("RowKey")
$list.Add("IntValue")

#Set query details.
$query.SelectColumns = $list
$query.TakeCount = 20

#Execute the query.
$entities = $table.CloudTable.ExecuteQuery($query)

#Display entity properties with the table format.
$entities  | Format-Table PartitionKey, RowKey, @{ Label = "IntValue"; Expression={$_.Properties["IntValue"].Int32Value}} -AutoSize
```

I also need commands to update a particular entity. Any help??

Answer (score 1):

Got it. Change the value of entity by doing `$entity.Properties["IntValue"].Int32Value` 
and then use this command to update that entity:

```
$result = $table.CloudTable.Execute([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation]::InsertOrReplace($entity))
```

`$Query.FilterString` can be used to get the specific entities from a table.